# Need to matrix below paragraph

Tags: bash

Need to add like below output in a matrix:

```
  pid: 41627404
  pro: fuser
  app:  1.189437
  sys:  30.108438
  hyp:  0.154453

--

  pid: 25306634
  pro: uv
  app:  7.953937
  sys:  2.474656
  hyp:  0.118188
```

--

Above is an output from a script and I need to simplify to read more easier ..

To header like below

```
pid pro app sys hyp
xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
yy  yy  yy  yy  yy
ect ....
```

Header should be as above and each assigned value from the script output should be under its title in header ,

any idea?

What I tried is a simple echo and for to make matrix needed , but I failed ...

Comment: Please explain what you meant by "need to matrix"?

Comment: Is "matrix" a verb? I think you'll probably need to explain your question better.

Comment: sometimes in our job you can verb the noun, sorry for that .. I edited again

Comment: And sorry, but you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Edit your Q to include your best attempt to solve this problem, and people may help you fix your current problem

Comment: .Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here on S.O.. Good luck.

Comment: done @shellter
i tired before my question already but failed hence i am asking now .. i didn't add my try it was a mess

Answer (score 1):

```
$for i in pid pro app sys
> do
> grep $i file |awk '{print $2}' > $i.out
>done
paste pid.out pro.out app.out sys.out
```

Thanks folks I have done what I needed, thanks for your help, thanks to Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this;

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n","pid","pro","app","sys","hyp")} {printf "%s%s",$2,NR%5?",":"\n" ; }'
```

or with tab sep.

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("%s\t\t%s\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n","pid","pro","app","sys","hyp")} {printf "%s\t%s", $2 ,NR%5?"":"\n" ; }'
```

eg;

```
user@host:/tmp/$ cat test
pid: 41627404
pro: fuser
app: 1.189437
sys: 30.108438
hyp: 0.154453
pid: 25306634
pro: uv
app: 7.953937
sys: 2.474656
hyp: 0.118188

user@host:/tmp/$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n","pid","pro","app","sys","hyp")} {printf "%s%s",$2,NR%5?",":"\n" ; }' test
pid,pro,app,sys,hyp
41627404,fuser,1.189437,30.108438,0.154453
25306634,uv,7.953937,2.474656,0.118188

user@host:/tmp/$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%s\t\t%s\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n","pid","pro","app","sys","hyp")} {printf "%s\t%s", $2 ,NR%5?"":"\n" ; }' test
pid     pro app     sys     hyp
41627404    fuser   1.189437    30.108438   0.154453    
25306634    uv  7.953937    2.474656    0.118188    
41627404    fuser   1.189437    30.108438   0.154453    
25306634    uv  7.953937    2.474656    0.118188    
41627404    fuser   1.189437    30.108438   0.154453    
25306634    uv  7.953937    2.474656    0.118188
```

Comment: looks nice, but i need to ask 2 questions...
1- what if I am having the third entry? should this work .. I tried already but it didn't ... actually I am having five in my output but i added 2 only to explain
2- What if need to add tab instead of ,

Comment: i am sorry but i don't have column .. its aix box ,, but i still under bash but little limitted with some linux tools

Comment: @mshafey : I updated ans. maybe this could help you.

Comment: thanks mustafa for your answer but it didn't work with more than 2 blocks also the output was not organized